# "Parameter validation failed: Invalid type for parameter" on update item in DynamoDB to a different type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

I need to update values in DynamoDB, original value is a string, new value is a number.
The error returned

> Parameter validation failed: Invalid type for parameter
> ExpressionAttributeValues.:ttl.N, value: 1696989709, type: <class
> 'int'>, valid types: <class 'str'>

Command:

```
aws dynamodb update-item \
--table-name my-datastore \
--key '{"Id": {"N": "456"}}'  \
--update-expression "SET expire_at = :ttl" \
--condition-expression "attribute_type(expire_at, :date_str)" \
--expression-attribute-values '{":ttl": {"N": 1696989709}, ":date_str": {"S": "S"}}'
```

CLI version is

```
aws-cli/2.11.21 Python/3.11.4 Darwin/21.6.0 source/arm64 prompt/off
```

The column 'expire_at' is specified on DynamoDB as TTL

```
   TimeToLiveSpecification:
     AttributeName: expire_at
     Enabled: true
```

Is there a way to update a string value to a number value?

**Update:**
When ttl is specified as

```
":ttl": {"N": "1696989709"}
```

it returns a different error:

> An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateItem
> operation: The provided key element does not match the schema

Table definition

```
aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name my-datastore;
{
    "Table": {
        "AttributeDefinitions": [
            {
                "AttributeName": "created_at",
                "AttributeType": "S"
            },
            {
                "AttributeName": "profile_key",
                "AttributeType": "S"
            },
            {
                "AttributeName": "user_id",
                "AttributeType": "S"
            }
        ],
        "TableName": "my-datastore",
        "KeySchema": [
            {
                "AttributeName": "user_id",
                "KeyType": "HASH"
            },
            {
                "AttributeName": "created_at",
                "KeyType": "RANGE"
            }
        ],
        "TableStatus": "ACTIVE",
        "CreationDateTime": "2023-06-21T14:50:16.470000-04:00",
        "ProvisionedThroughput": {
            "LastDecreaseDateTime": "2023-06-21T15:02:10.890000-04:00",
            "NumberOfDecreasesToday": 0,
            "ReadCapacityUnits": 5,
            "WriteCapacityUnits": 5
        },
        "TableSizeBytes": 1439,
        "ItemCount": 9,
        "TableArn": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:{acct}:table/my-datastore",
        "TableId": "{table-id}",
        "GlobalSecondaryIndexes": [
            {
                "IndexName": "by_profile_key",
                "KeySchema": [
                    {
                        "AttributeName": "profile_key",
                        "KeyType": "HASH"
                    },
                    {
                        "AttributeName": "created_at",
                        "KeyType": "RANGE"
                    }
                ],
                "Projection": {
                    "ProjectionType": "ALL"
                },
                "IndexStatus": "ACTIVE",
                "ProvisionedThroughput": {
                    "NumberOfDecreasesToday": 0,
                    "ReadCapacityUnits": 5,
                    "WriteCapacityUnits": 5
                },
                "IndexSizeBytes": 1439,
                "ItemCount": 9,
                "IndexArn": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:{account}:table/my-datastore/index/by_profile_key"
            }
        ],
        "SSEDescription": {
            "Status": "ENABLED",
            "SSEType": "KMS",
            "KMSMasterKeyArn": "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:{account}:key/{key}"
        },
        "DeletionProtectionEnabled": false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jason stated, change the TTL value in expressionAttributeValues:

```
aws dynamodb update-item \
--table-name my-datastore \
--key '{"Id": {"N": "456"}}'  \
--update-expression "SET expire_at = :ttl" \
--condition-expression "attribute_type(expire_at, :date_str)" \
--expression-attribute-values '{":ttl": {"N": "1696989709"}, ":date_str": {"S": "S"}}'
```

As for the exception:

> An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateItem operation: The provided key element does not match the schema

You need to also show us the output of:

```
aws dynamodb describe-table \
--table-name my-datastore
```

---

Works for me:

#### Before

```
aws dynamodb get-item \
--table-name my-datastore \
--key '{"Id":{"N":"456"}}' \
--consistent-read

{
    "Item": {
        "Id": {
            "N": "456"
        },
        "expire_at": {
            "S": "2384023948"
        }
    }
}
```

#### Update

```
aws dynamodb update-item \
--table-name my-datastore \
--key '{"Id": {"N": "456"}}'  \
--update-expression "SET expire_at = :ttl" \
--condition-expression "attribute_type(expire_at, :date_str)" \
--expression-attribute-values '{":ttl": {"N": "1696989709"}, ":date_str": {"S": "S"}}'
```

#### After

```
aws dynamodb get-item \
--table-name my-datastore \
--key '{"Id":{"N":"456"}}' \
--consistent-read
{
    "Item": {
        "Id": {
            "N": "456"
        },
        "expire_at": {
            "N": "1696989709"
        }
    }
}
```

### Update

Based on your update you're trying to update an item without specifying it's keys `user_id` and `created_at`, without specifying both those values you will not be able to update the item.

#### Request

```
aws dynamodb update-item \
--table-name my-datastore \
--key '{"user_id": {"S": "some-user-id"}, {"create_at": {"S": "some-created_at-value"}}'  \
--update-expression "SET expire_at = :ttl" \
--condition-expression "attribute_type(expire_at, :date_str)" \
--expression-attribute-values '{":ttl": {"N": "1696989709"}, ":date_str": {"S": "S"}}'
```

Comment: This produces this error: 
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateItem operation: The provided key element does not match the schema

Comment: show me the output of `describe-table`

Comment: Added output of describe-table to the question. Also posted CLI version.

Comment: Lee, thank you. Can you post syntax on how to specify the full key for the item?

Comment: Updated to show at the end of the answer. You  need the values for user_id and created_at

Answer (score 1):

You need to put quotes around your number value, same as you did for the key value. Numbers are passed in as strings.

Comment: No, that doesn't work. Updated the question.